# Probabilistic degree of confidence for the kernel SVM with RBF

Tags: probability, classification, svm, kernel-trick

Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be the decision function of an SVM using the radial basis function (RBF), 
$$
k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')=\exp\Big(-\gamma\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'\|^2\Big).
$$
That is,
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_i) + \rho,
$$
where $a_i\in\Bbb{R}$, $\forall i=1,\ldots,N$, and $\mathbf{x}_i\in\Bbb{R}^n$ is the $i$-th support vector (SV).

The label of an unseen, testing datum, $\mathbf{x}_t$, is determined by the sign of the decision function $f$ when evaluated on $\mathbf{x}_t$, i.e.,
$$
y_t = \operatorname{sgn}\big(f(\mathbf{x}_t)\big).
$$

What would be an appropriate and meaningful strategy in order to additionally compute a **probabilistic** "degree of confidence", $p_t\in[0.1]$, expressing the confidence for assigning the label $y_t$ to the testing sample $\mathbf{x}_t$?

Concerning my attempts, I tried the sigmoid function, but it does not work. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Platt scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15112563/344821) is the standard method. It's supported natively in libsvm.

Comment: Thanks @Dougal, I saw that in the libsvm paper, but didn't really get it. I implement my own svm-like classifier, so I need to implement this too. I wonder how difficult would be to find $A,B$? Have you ever tried to do it by yourself?

Comment: The libsvm authors wrote [a paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/plattprob.pdf) about implementing it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said right above ("I saw that in the libsvm paper"), but I find it a bit vague... Thanks anyway! You actually answered my question.

Comment: There are multiple libsvm papers, and I thought you were talking about the general implementation paper, not this one. It's a pretty explicit discussion of implementing the algorithm; if there are things you don't get, feel free to ask....

Comment: My bad @Dougal, I never clicked on the link, I just thought you were talking about the well-known and general implementation paper. So, yes, this is much more informative, I will study it and I will return to ask some question, if necessary! Thanks again!